# Yandex MapKit set locale of labels

Tags: android, locale, yandex-mapkit

How can I set the label locale in mapkit?

MapKit dont use default localization for text marks

```
 mapView.getMap()
```

does not contain suitable methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i did it

**Docs:** [i18ManagerFactory](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/runtime/ref/com/yandex/runtime/i18n/I18nManagerFactory-docpage/#method_detail__method_setLocale___NonNullString___NonNullString___NonNullLocaleUpdateListener)

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
    MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
    .....
    I18nManagerFactory.setLocale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), new LocaleUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocaleUpdated() {
            Log.d(TAG","onLocaleUpdated");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocaleUpdateError(@NonNull Error error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onLocaleUpdateError");
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Country and Language settings are determined by system preferences. And user needs to restart the application for the changes to take effect.